# overwrite javascript standard submit function behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a huge webapplication I need a workaround for submitting forms.

For overriding a built-in javscript method I tried [this example](http://greasemonkey.win-start.de/patterns/override-method.html), but I don't even get the alert popup.

My idea for the overwritten submit function is this:

```
function submit(event) {
        var target = event ? event.target : this;
        $.ajax({
            url: target.action,
            data: $('form').serialize(), // &nd someone knows how I can get the serialize() of the form I just clicked?
            success: function (data) {
                alert('done');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('error (check console log)');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        //this._submit();
        return false;
    }
```

The way the submit is used everywhere is not consistent. Possiblities in the original code:

```
<button onclick="form.submit">
onclick="calltoFunction();" // where inside the function the submit is called
<button type="submit" // the normal way
```

I guess my idea is possible, because I overwritten js-functions before. But how should I do it with the submit part.
Any suggestions, ideas, fixes are welcome!

Comment: You don't have **type** attr in ajax function!

Comment: I do, in ajaxsetup. Sorry for not mentioning. Also tried it with putting that attr in the function, no result.

Answer (score 2):

Bind the event to your button like so:

```
$('#my_button').click(
    function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //This will prevent the buttons default submit behavior
        ...//The rest is up to you!
}
);
```

Comment: My bad, I looked at the part of the code that mattered + the tags and didn't see it there.

Comment: I want to overwrite the standard javascript submit method, so I can't use yours. I did return false btw, works the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
function submit(form) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('done');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('error (check console log)');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

<form id="my-form" action="/my-action-file.php" method="post" onsubmit="return submit('#my-form');">
    <!-- my form content -->
</form>
```

Comment: That's indeed a simple thing to do, but not an option in this case, see startpost, but thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you will find this useful:

```
$('#yourForm').beforeSubmit(function()
{
    return doWhateverYouLikeAndReturnTrueToContinueFormSubmition($(this));
});
```

This will execute doWhateverYouLikeAndReturnTrueToContinueFormSubmition **before** any other form submission code

Comment: Didn't see that function before. But what I want is to send the data with Ajax. Not possible with the beforeSubmit in this case. I still shall submit the form after that function.

Comment: I fail to see what will prevent you from making AJAX calls from `doWhateverYouLikeAndReturnTrueToContinueFormSubmition()`

Comment: I want to overwrite the original submit function. So without using ID's. Because the application has tons of forms, and they need a quick workaround to submit them by ajax. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Usually you have one (not many) forms in single page. Even if you do have many forms in the page you can run the same code in foreach loop 
`for thisForm : document.getElementsByTagName ('form') {
thisForm.beforeSubmit(function()
{
    return doWhateverYouLikeAndReturnTrueToContinueFormSubmition(thisForm);
});
}
`

Comment: Can't get it to work.. How to make a beforeSubmit for ALL forms, with still the normal functionality of the submit. For example: beforeSubmit > send a message with alert() > then do the normal things the submit always does..

Comment: What exactly does not work and how? You can't run **my** code? You can't call AJAX from within the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function submit(event) {
    var target = event ? event.target : this;
    $.ajax({
        url: target.action,
        type: "POST",
        data: $('form').serialize(), // &nd someone knows how I can get the serialize() of the form I just clicked?
        success: function (data) {
            alert('done');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('error (check console log)');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    //this._submit();
    return false;
    }
```